# Cast to decimal(18,2) in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT 
[nu_ano],
[nu_mes],
[id_projeto],
[id_fase],
'Financial Progress ("Competência")' as ds_categoria,
'Baseline' as ds_curva,
vl_baseline as vl_curva,
cast((vl_baseline / (pc_baseline / 100)) as decimal(18,2)) as vl_curva_total
FROM [Alvarez_Marsal].[dbo].[Schedule_Status]
```

And my LINQ query is like this:

```
var result = (from l in db.Schedule_Status
        .Where(x => x.nu_mes == 12)
            .Select(x => new Retorno
            {
            nu_ano = x.nu_ano,
            nu_mes = x.nu_mes,
            id_projeto = x.id_projeto,
            id_fase = x.id_fase,
            ds_categoria = "Financial Progress ('Competência')",
            ds_curva = "Baseline",
            vl_curva = x.vl_baseline,
            vl_curva_total = decimal.Round((decimal)(x.vl_baseline / x.pc_baseline / 100), 2)
            })
        select l);
```

Transforming my LINQ query in SQL query, the result is:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[nu_ano] AS [nu_ano], 
[Extent1].[nu_mes] AS [nu_mes], 
[Extent1].[id_projeto] AS [id_projeto], 
[Extent1].[id_fase] AS [id_fase], 
N'Financial Progress (''Competência'')' AS [C1], 
N'Baseline' AS [C2], 
[Extent1].[vl_baseline] AS [vl_baseline], 
ROUND(([Extent1].[vl_baseline] / [Extent1].[pc_baseline]) / cast(100 as decimal(18)), 2) AS [C3]
FROM [dbo].[Schedule_Status] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 12 = [Extent1].[nu_mes]
```

Class Retorno

```
        class Retorno
        {
        public int nu_ano { get; set; }
        public short nu_mes { get; set; }
        public int id_projeto { get; set; }
        public int id_fase { get; set; }
        public string ds_categoria { get; set; }
        public string ds_curva { get; set; }
        public decimal? vl_curva { get; set; }
        public decimal? vl_curva_total { get; set; }

        }
```

Given that there is no Convert.ToDecimal() in SQL language, how could I transcribe **as decimal(18,2)** in LINQ? is it possible? I have tried using decimal.Round() but it is not working.

The field vl_curva_total in my LINQ query is returning 
3000.0000000000000000000 while correct would be to return 30000000.00

Comment: I don't think it is possible. You could add an `AsEnumerable` call before the `Select` to pull the column over unconverted and do the conversion on the client side.

Comment: You wrote *The field vl_curva_totalin my LINQ query is returning 3000.0000000000000000000 while correct would be to return 30000000.00* It is still rounded to 2 places after the comma, just added zeros. Does it return values that are not rounded?

Comment: @zᴉɹɥƆ If i use (18,2) as SQL query the result will be the same. My intention is to transform this  3000.0000000000000000000 to 30000000.00. I've just used the Round because it was my best idea to match the Cast(18,2) to LINQ

Comment: @LeonardoLima My fault, I just noticed that you should get a way higher number (10000times more) than your current output. I just focused on .00 vs .00...000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your order of operations has changed between the two queries.

**SQL Query**

```
(vl_baseline / (pc_baseline / 100))
```

**LINQ Query**

```
(x.vl_baseline / x.pc_baseline / 100)
```

This explains the difference in the two values (3000 vs 30000000). Simply add the parentheses to your `LINQ` query to fix this.

```
(x.vl_baseline / (x.pc_baseline / 100))
```

Comment: Actually x is the class "Retorno". I edited the question.

Comment: @LeonardoLima He isn't referencing the `x`, you're missing the parentheses and changed the order of operations.

Comment: My fault, I missed that it's 3000 vs 30000000. I was only focused on .00 vs .000000. If you edit your answer I'll remove my downvote (otherwise I'm not able to). I deleted my false accusement